# ¿Cómo dar privilegios a los usuarios de mi punto de venta?

Tags: java, jdbc

Tengo un sistema que es un punto de venta realizado en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans). En mi sistema pueden registrarse 2 tipos de usuarios:

- Administrador
- Vendedor

Hay varios módulos en el sistema, entre ellos el modulo "Inventario" que te permite ingresar, modificar, eliminar y buscar artículos en la base de datos, el problema es que yo quiero que solo el administrador tenga permisos para ingresar a ese módulo, y que el vendedor no pueda acceder a él.

### Código fuente

A continuación les dejo el código del método "ListarUsuarios" que se encuentra en otra clase llamada "LoginDAO":

```
public List ListarUsuarios(){
    List<login> ListaUsuarios = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
    try{
        con = cn.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            login ld = new login();
            ld.setId_usuario(rs.getInt("id_usuario"));
            ld.setTipoUsuario(rs.getString("tipoUsuario"));
            ld.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
            //ld.setApellido_paterno(rs.getString("apellido_paterno"));
            //ld.setApellido_materno(rs.getString("apellido_materno"));
            ld.setContrasena(rs.getString("contrasena"));
            ListaUsuarios.add(ld);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return ListaUsuarios;
}
```

Y por último les dejo el código de la clase "login", que es donde se encuentran los sets y gets de la información de cada usuario:

```
package Modelo;
//Constructor para varibles del Usario con getters y seters
public class login {
private int id_usuario;
private String nombre;
private String apellido_paterno;
private String apellido_materno;
private String tipoUsuario;
private String contrasena;
private String correo;
private int id_proveedor;
private String nombre_proveedor;
private String telefono_proveedor;
private String direccion_proveedor;
private String domicilio_proveedor;
private String email_proveedor;

public login() {
}

public String getDomicilio_proveedor() {
    return domicilio_proveedor;
}

public void setDomicilio_proveedor(String domicilio_proveedor) {
    this.domicilio_proveedor = domicilio_proveedor;
}

public login(int id_usuario, String nombre, String contrasena, String tipoUsuario, int id_proveedor,String nombre_proveedor,String telefono_proveedor,String direccion_proveedor,String email_proveedor) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.id_proveedor = id_proveedor;
    this.nombre_proveedor = nombre_proveedor;
    this.telefono_proveedor = telefono_proveedor;
    this.direccion_proveedor = direccion_proveedor;
    this.email_proveedor = email_proveedor;
}

public int getId_proveedor() {
    return id_proveedor;
}

public void setId_proveedor(int id_proveedor) {
    this.id_proveedor = id_proveedor;
}



public String getNombre_proveedor() {
    return nombre_proveedor;
}

public void setNombre_proveedor(String nombre_proveedor) {
    this.nombre_proveedor = nombre_proveedor;
}

public String getTelefono_proveedor() {
    return telefono_proveedor;
}

public void setTelefono_proveedor(String telefono_proveedor) {
    this.telefono_proveedor = telefono_proveedor;
}

public String getDireccion_proveedor() {
    return direccion_proveedor;
}

public void setDireccion_proveedor(String direccion_proveedor) {
    this.direccion_proveedor = direccion_proveedor;
}

public String getEmail_proveedor() {
    return email_proveedor;
}

public void setEmail_proveedor(String email_proveedor) {
    this.email_proveedor = email_proveedor;
}

public int getId_usuario() {
    return id_usuario;
}

public String getApellido_paterno() {
    return apellido_paterno;
}

public void setApellido_paterno(String apellido_paterno) {
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
}

public String getApellido_materno() {
    return apellido_materno;
}

public void setApellido_materno(String apellido_materno) {
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
}

public String getTipoUsuario() {
    return tipoUsuario;
}

public void setTipoUsuario(String tipoUsuario) {
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public void setId_usuario(int id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getContrasena() {
    return contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}
   
}
```

### Intentos

Tenia una idea que era poner un código así en el método del botón "Inventario" para prohibirle entrar pero no me funcionó; el código era así:

```
    //"usu" es el objeto de la clase "Login", que es donde declaro los sets y gets de la informacion del usuario
    String tUsuario=usu.getTipoUsuario();
   
    if(tUsuario.equals("admin"))
    {
    LimpiarTable();
    ListarArticulo();
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

El problema es que no funcionaba el código, y al imprimir que valor estaba tomando el "getTipoUsuario" me decía que estaba retornando el valor "null".
Intente con otro código para intentar tomar el valor de la variable "tipoUsuario" por medio de la variable "id_usuario"; el código es el siguiente:

```
//"login" es la clase donde tengo toda la informacion de los usuarios, los sets y gets, "usuarios es el objeto de otra clase llamada "loginDAO""
List<login> ListarUsuario = usuarios.ListarUsuarios();
   modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaUsuarios.getModel();
    Object [] ob = new Object[4];
    for(int i=0; i < ListarUsuario.size();i++){
        ob[0] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getId_usuario();
        ob[1] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getTipoUsuario();
        ob[2] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getNombre();
        //ob[3] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getApellido_paterno();
        //ob[4] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getApellido_materno();
        ob[3] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getContrasena();
        modelo.addRow(ob);
    }
        int tID  = usu.getId_usuario();
    String tUsuario = ListarUsuario.get(tID).getTipoUsuario();//usu.getTipoUsuario();
   
    if(tUsuario.equals("admin"))
    {
    LimpiarTable();
    ListarArticulo();
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

El problema con el código anterior es que cuando le daba imprimir al valor de "tUsuario" siempre me daba el tipoUsuario del primero de la lista, no de los demás.

¿Por qué no funcionan mis códigos o por qué la variable "tUsuario" me retorna "null"? O si mis métodos están mal, ¿cuál sería un método que sirva para eso?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que noto es que estás tratando de guardar tus contraseñas como tipo String lo cual es un mega problema de seguridad, al respecto te recomiendo leer [este artículo que hice](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/java-string-inmutables-por-diseno/).

Lo segundo es que estás mezclando en el mismo lugar código para inicio de sesión, junto con el llenado de tablas lo cual va en contra de la S de SOLID, esto no es la causa del problema pero sí la causa de que tu código te parezca confuso y difícil de modificar, teniendo el problema adicional de que estas cargando todas las contraseñas de todos los usuarios y si alguien intentara hackearte tu aplicación podría fácilmente crackearla yo robarte toda la información de tus usuarios.

Una práctica que puede ayudarte es la de separar en capas tu aplicación y para ello te propongo un servicio de inicio de sesión

```
private void loginAttempt() {
    String user = txtUser.getText();
    if (!user.isEmpty()) {
        String password = txtPsswd.getText();

        LoginUser loginUser = new LoginUser(user, password);

        try {
            if (usersService.authenticate(loginUser)) {
                if (authorizationService.userHasRole("Admin")) {
                    navigationHandler.goToAdminMenu(this);
                } else {
                    navigationHandler.goToMenu(this);
                }
                clearFields();
                return;
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario " + user + " no encontrado", "Credenciales incorrectas", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        } catch (HttpServerErrorException hsee) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "El servicio está experimentando problemas.", hsee);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El servicio está experimentando problemas, favor de reportar con la hora exacta", "Problema del servidor", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (ResourceAccessException ex) {
            log.log(Level.INFO, "Hubo un problema al comunicarse con el servidor.", ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hubo un problema al comunicarse con el servidor, por favor reintente en unos segundos", "Problema de comunicación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí la clase LoginUser se usa para guardar los valores ingresados en el intento, no los valores de la base de datos y sería la variable a la que estás llamando `usu`.

El código del primer intento en su primera línea iría en la clase `AuthorizationService` en el método `userHasRole(String role)` pero en vez de hacer cosas allí solo regresarías true o false dependiendo de si tiene el rol o no.

Para la clase `UsersService` en su método `authenticate` sería algo similar, te recomiendo que allí en vez de usar tu lista de usuarios uses una consulta similar a

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre =\""+loginUser.getUser()+"\"" and contrasena=\""+loginUser.getPassword()+"\"";
```

pero usando [prepared-statements](/questions/tagged/prepared-statements) para evitar que las contraseñas se queden en memoria y para evitar inyecciones sql.

Tengo un proyecto hecho con spring donde puedes ver como integro esto usando arquitectura de microservicios [en mi github](https://github.com/javatlacati/Inventarios/tree/master/inventarios-desktop) para tener un sistema de roles y permisos.

Inténtalo y si te atoras edita tu pregunta con el nuevo intento, escríbeme un comentario en esta respuesta y con gusto la actualizo.