# ¿Como puedo asignarle privilegios a mis usuarios en un sistema para acceder a diferentes modulos?

Tags: java, jdbc

Buenas noches a todos!.

Tengo un sistema que es un punto de venta realizado en netbeans. En mi sistema pueden registrarse 2 tipos de usuarios:

```
Administrador
Vendedor
```

Hay varios módulos en el sistema, entre ellos el modulo "Inventario" que te permite ingresar, modificar, eliminar y buscar artículos en la base de datos, el problema es que yo quiero que solo el administrador tenga permisos para ingresar a ese módulo, y que el vendedor no pueda acceder a él.
Código fuente

A continuación les dejo el código del método "ListarUsuarios" que se encuentra en otra clase llamada "LoginDAO":

```
public List ListarUsuarios(){
List<login> ListaUsuarios = new ArrayList();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
try{
    con = cn.getConnection();
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        login ld = new login();
        ld.setId_usuario(rs.getInt("id_usuario"));
        ld.setTipoUsuario(rs.getString("tipoUsuario"));
        ld.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
        //ld.setApellido_paterno(rs.getString("apellido_paterno"));
        //ld.setApellido_materno(rs.getString("apellido_materno"));
        ld.setContrasena(rs.getString("contrasena"));
        ListaUsuarios.add(ld);
    }
}catch(SQLException e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
return ListaUsuarios;
```

}

Y por último les dejo el código de la clase "login", que es donde se encuentran los sets y gets de la información de cada usuario:

```
package Modelo;
//Constructor para varibles del Usario con getters y seters
public class login {
private int id_usuario;
private String nombre;
private String apellido_paterno;
private String apellido_materno;
private String tipoUsuario;
private String contrasena;
private String correo;
private int id_proveedor;
private String nombre_proveedor;
private String telefono_proveedor;
private String direccion_proveedor;
private String domicilio_proveedor;
private String email_proveedor;

public login() {
}

public String getDomicilio_proveedor() {
    return domicilio_proveedor;
}

public void setDomicilio_proveedor(String domicilio_proveedor) {
    this.domicilio_proveedor = domicilio_proveedor;
}

public login(int id_usuario, String nombre, String contrasena, String tipoUsuario, int id_proveedor,String nombre_proveedor,String telefono_proveedor,String direccion_proveedor,String email_proveedor) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.id_proveedor = id_proveedor;
    this.nombre_proveedor = nombre_proveedor;
    this.telefono_proveedor = telefono_proveedor;
    this.direccion_proveedor = direccion_proveedor;
    this.email_proveedor = email_proveedor;
}

public int getId_proveedor() {
    return id_proveedor;
}

public void setId_proveedor(int id_proveedor) {
    this.id_proveedor = id_proveedor;
}



public String getNombre_proveedor() {
    return nombre_proveedor;
}

public void setNombre_proveedor(String nombre_proveedor) {
    this.nombre_proveedor = nombre_proveedor;
}

public String getTelefono_proveedor() {
    return telefono_proveedor;
}

public void setTelefono_proveedor(String telefono_proveedor) {
    this.telefono_proveedor = telefono_proveedor;
}

public String getDireccion_proveedor() {
    return direccion_proveedor;
}

public void setDireccion_proveedor(String direccion_proveedor) {
    this.direccion_proveedor = direccion_proveedor;
}

public String getEmail_proveedor() {
    return email_proveedor;
}

public void setEmail_proveedor(String email_proveedor) {
    this.email_proveedor = email_proveedor;
}

public int getId_usuario() {
    return id_usuario;
}

public String getApellido_paterno() {
    return apellido_paterno;
}

public void setApellido_paterno(String apellido_paterno) {
    this.apellido_paterno = apellido_paterno;
}

public String getApellido_materno() {
    return apellido_materno;
}

public void setApellido_materno(String apellido_materno) {
    this.apellido_materno = apellido_materno;
}

public String getTipoUsuario() {
    return tipoUsuario;
}

public void setTipoUsuario(String tipoUsuario) {
    this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public void setId_usuario(int id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getContrasena() {
    return contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}
```

}

**Intentos**

Tenia una idea que era poner un código así en el método del botón "Inventario" para prohibirle entrar pero no me funcionó; el código era así:

```
//"usu" es el objeto de la clase "Login", que es donde declaro los sets y gets de la informacion del usuario
String tUsuario=usu.getTipoUsuario();

    if(tUsuario.equals("admin"))
    {
    LimpiarTable();
    ListarArticulo();
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

El problema es que no funcionaba el código, y al imprimir que valor estaba tomando el "getTipoUsuario" me decía que estaba retornando el valor "null". Intente con otro código para intentar tomar el valor de la variable "tipoUsuario" por medio de la variable "id_usuario"; el código es el siguiente:

```
//"login" es la clase donde tengo toda la informacion de los usuarios, los sets y gets, "usuarios es el objeto de otra clase llamada "loginDAO""
List<login> ListarUsuario = usuarios.ListarUsuarios();
   modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablaUsuarios.getModel();
    Object [] ob = new Object[4];
    for(int i=0; i < ListarUsuario.size();i++){
        ob[0] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getId_usuario();
        ob[1] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getTipoUsuario();
        ob[2] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getNombre();
        //ob[3] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getApellido_paterno();
        //ob[4] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getApellido_materno();
        ob[3] = ListarUsuario.get(i).getContrasena();
        modelo.addRow(ob);
    }
        int tID  = usu.getId_usuario();
    String tUsuario = ListarUsuario.get(tID).getTipoUsuario();//usu.getTipoUsuario();

    if(tUsuario.equals("admin"))
    {
    LimpiarTable();
    ListarArticulo();
    jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }
```

El problema con el código anterior es que cuando le daba imprimir al valor de "tUsuario" siempre me daba el tipoUsuario del primero de la lista, no de los demás.

¿Por qué no funcionan mis códigos o por qué la variable "tUsuario" me retorna "null"? O si mis métodos están mal, ¿cuál sería un método que sirva para eso?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo dar privilegios a los usuarios de mi punto de venta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/596552/c%c3%b3mo-dar-privilegios-a-los-usuarios-de-mi-punto-de-venta)